# User Directory contents lost after Catalina combo update

Tags: catalina, software-update, data-recovery, logs

I was updating the Catalina Combo update, and after a while, the update is still there pending but many of my applications and most importantly All my directories and files in my home directory are lost.

I tried to look into the logs but couldn't able to make any sense.

I really appreciate it if someone can help me out to find out what exactly happened and why I lost the directories and other content in my home directory. Or provide a hint where should I look for it.

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine or other backup of your Mac?

Comment: Catalina splits the system disk into two volumes: one called "Macintosh HD", which only contains the Apple-installed apps and OS files. The other is called "Macintosh HD - Data", and that's where all your apps and user files are stored. The OS then presents the two as one 'merged' volume in the Finder. 
See if the second volume exists. It sounds like the OS update split the disk but didn't complete. I presume you have a backup?

Comment: @IconDaemon No, Time Machine has never been configured on the system.

Comment: @benwiggy, unfortunately I dont have any backup. Getting back data is a plus.
I generally search into the terminal. Files lost at /Users/xxxx/